# {{media url="..."}} doesn't work on product attributes

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, frontend, wysiwyg, media

After magento update to version 2.3.2 i noticed that `{{media url="..."}}` is not working on product attributes like 'description' attribute. In backend the url is resolved correctly and i can see the image in the editor. But in frontend i see `<img src="{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/......jpg&quot;}}" alt="">`
Someone else having this problem? Or best way to debug and solve this problem?

Comment: did you check log file?

Comment: yes i checked the exceptions logs, system and debug, i found nothing